# How to fetch all values of a column based on value of another column in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following structure:

```
admin_id  ||  country_id 
---------------------------------
 1              2      
 5              1
 1              2
 2              3
 5              62
 1              1
 3              62
```

How to fetch all values by taking the `$_SESSION['admin']['id']`, finding the country_id of that admin and getting all other admin_id and country_id that are the same of the session admin?

So, lets say the currently logged in admin has `id` = 5 , that means the admin_id: 5 has two country_id: 1 and 62. I want to take all rows that have country_id: 1 and 62.

It should return this:

```
admin_id || country_id 
------------------------        
 5              1  
 5              62
 1              1
 3              62
```

How can I do this in one sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause for filtering on the `admin_id` or the `country_id`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.admin_id = 5 or
      t.country_id in (select t2.country_id from t t2 where t2.admin_id = 5);
```

Comment: `t.admin_id = 5` is excess - all rows matched this condition matches the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (country_id)
WHERE t2.admin_id = 5
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6ae05b555461a8e408544d556184364)